# cannot create a react native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I had installed node js with the newest version and then used the command  `npm install -g expo-cli` to `install expo cli`. But then when I enter command to create a new project `expo init AwesomeProject`, I receive this error:

[image]

my command line shows this error. Would anyone know how to solve this..?

Comment: Try running the command with higher privileges!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following these steps:

1. Uninstall expo-cli
2. sudo npm install -g expo-cli
3. expo init